# Logitech G432 headset mic does not work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: pulseaudio, logitech

I have bought recently the wired Logitech G432 headset. They speakers sounds ok, but the mic does not sound at all.
[image]

I have tried also with pulse audio.
[image]

Comment: Is this device wired or Bluetooth?

Comment: the headset is wired